# Jsoup split block element to preserve order of text and child elements

Tags: java, jsoup

Lets say I have an html fragment like this:

```
<p>Generally speaking, in the U.S., if you want to <a href="\&quot;https://web.archive.org/web/20210408195204/https://www.wsj.com/articles/investors-big-and-small-are-driving-stock-gains-with-borrowed-money-11617799940\&quot;"> 
  borrow money from your broker to buy stocks</a>, you are capped at 2-to-1 leverage. If you have $100, you can buy $200 worth of stock. Back in the olden days, you could have bought&nbsp;$300 or $500 or $1,000 of stock with your $100, borrowing the rest from your broker, but then a Great Depression happened and regulators clamped down on margin lending. </p>
```

I've parsed it with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) and its represented as an [Element](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html).

I'd like to be able to split the element into something like:

- A fragment of text: `"Generally speaking, in the U.S., if you want to "`
- an Element `<a href="\&quot;https://web.archive.org/web/20210408195204/https://www.wsj.com/articles/investors-big-and-small-are-driving-stock-gains-with-borrowed-money-11617799940\&quot;">`
- Another fragment of text: `"borrow money from your broker to buy stocks</a>, you are capped at 2-to-1 leverage. If you have $100, you can buy $200 worth of stock. Back in the olden days, you could have bought&nbsp;$300 or $500 or $1,000 of stock with your $100, borrowing the rest from your broker, but then a Great Depression happened and regulators clamped down on margin lending"`

And do this while preserving the ordering of those pieces.

Things I've looked at so far:

- getAllElements() only returns the p tag itself at index 0 and then the element for the a tag
- children() only returns 1 element for the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `childNodes()` method. Then you get a `List<Node>`. You can work with these nodes, access their attributes and parents, but you lose the possibility to use `select()` to access deeper tags because only `Element` class has this method.